# jQuery: get elements above a given 'y' position

Tags: jquery, positioning

How can you do this with jQuery, in an elegant way?

> Apply `z` attribute *(e.g.: red background)* to every children of a div `parent`
>   while their position is above a given top-offset `y`.

I've tried in different ways, but I'm not happy with any of them...
I know there must be a short  and elegant way to do it...

Comment: Is the top position relative to the document, or the viewable portion of the document, or to the parent div?

Comment: let's say is relative to the document, that will be simpler (in the reality, it's relative to the position of a parent's sibling)

Comment: So when the page scrolls, it doesn't change which elements are affected. That sound right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're saying you've tried a few ways, and you're just looking for something more elegant, I'll assume you have the offset part worked out, and I'll just go with `offset` myself. Modify that part as needed. For elegance, you could create a custom selector checking top offset:

```
$.expr[':'].above = function(obj, index, meta, stack) { 
    return $(obj).offset().top < meta[3];
}
```

You could then query it as such:

```
$('#myParentDiv').find('div:above(100)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Of course this could just as well have been expressed as

```
$('#myParentDiv div:above(100)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

or, as pointed out in comments

```
var y = 100;
$('#myParentDiv div:above('+y+')').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: +1, I would not have thought of writing my own pseudo-selector. Cool!

Comment: Fantastic! This is pure elegance! And what if I want to give to the selector a variable as argument (e.g., `var y = 100;` ... `....find('div:above(y)')...` )?

Comment: @dolma: that will not work, because `y` is just a character in a string. You would need to do this: `...find('div:above(' + y + ')')...`

Comment: @DavidHedlund Amazing answer, can you explain to me what is the meaning of meta[3]? I am trying get the near by div around my div (like Minesweeper)

Comment: @Michel: `meta`, here, contains all the information about the pseudo selector used. in `div:above(30)` it would be an array that looks like `[":above(30)","above","","30"]`. Hence, `meta[0]` is the entire pseudo-selector being evaluated, `meta[1]` is the name of the selector only, `meta[2]` is whether double or single quotes are wrapping the value; in our case neither. `meta[3]` which is all I'm interested in, is the input parameter, which will be `"30"`. If we built a pseudo selector that said `:between(30,50)` then `meta[3]` would be `"30,50"` and we'd have to parse the string from there.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Really appreciate your attention to my comment, I'm gonna try out in my little Minesweeper. Thanks =)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should get the job done:

```
var y = 250,
    RED = '#F00';

$('#parent > *').css('background-color', function (i, v)
{
    if ($(this).offset().top < y)
    {
        return RED;
    }
    return v;
});
```

The selector `'#parent > *'` will select all immediate children (not all descendants) of the element with id `parent`. I assume that's what you're looking for, since you said "apply...  to every children of a div `parent`."

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/87QFU/1/

Comment: +1 but if you already have a jQuery object for parent you can also use parent.children() for first-level children or parent.find('*') for the entire subtree.

Comment: Since OP is asking for the position *above* a given offset, you probably want to compare `< y` since the Y at top is 0.

Comment: @Jason: you're right, but I'm not sure I see you're getting at. Selector optimization? That's not what this question is about.

Comment: I really like it, but I think it still could be more efficient: in this way, I'm *testing every children*; but if the elements are _e.g._ `<p>` or `<li>`, it _could be logic_ to assume that if I have a children below `y`, the other childrens after this one will be below `y`too, so we could economize on  the next tests.

Comment: @dolma: that kind of optimization is totally up to you. For a generic implementation, however, you can't necessarily assume that. For example, you might be using a stylesheet with this rule `#parent > *:last-child { position: fixed; top: 0; }` - in which case, your optimization does not work correctly.

Comment: @dolma: In general, don't worry about optimization until performance is actually a problem.

Comment: @Matt: I know, I know... I'm obsessed with optimization, and this could be a problem for me, because sometimes I really can't do  simple things in 5 minutes, and I find myself losing days on them... BTW, when do you think that performance becomes a real problem, in this case? Maybe when only 10 over 500 elements are above the `y`? Or with something bigger, like only 10 over 4000? Or never?

Comment: @dolma: in this specific case, performance is a problem when you/your boss/your client (basically, whoever you're developing for) notices that things are taking too long. Remember, when you're using jQuery, you're already taking a performance hit, but the point isn't performance - it's that **developer time is worth more than CPU time**. Let me say this again, because it **is** that imporant. **Developer time is worth more than CPU time.** jQuery saves **you** - the developer - time by allowing you to write DOM code that works across all browsers, so you can write code that is actually more...

Comment: ...valuable **to the end user**, rather than spend 3 days trying to figure out why _!@#$%ing IE won't $&*(%ing obey you_.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt... I'll keep it in mind everytime I'll find myself stuck while fighting for performance and perfection!

Answer (score 1):

Are the childrens dynamically placed with top-offset or do they all have a common css-class?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $("div").children(".offsetelement").css("background-color", "red");
 </script>
```