# x and y position. minesweeper style

Tags: jquery, positioning

When I click with my [left-button](/questions/tagged/left-button) it should works like the image below.

[image]

But instead, my code is doing this.

[image]

I made an example (see the fiddle below). As you can see in the image, my current problem is:

**All the above and below (not only the first row) are changing too.**

*In my fiddle example, I'm using `.css('background-color', 'red')` to test it.*

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Nymos/RCRQJ/1/)

I gathered information in those two posts.

- [jQuery x y document coordinates of DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object)
- [jQuery: get elements above a given 'y' position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195620/jquery-get-elements-above-a-given-y-position)

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Left + right click simultaneously is not the best design idea. For example, Mac laptop users would have a very hard time with that, and I'm sure there are many others who would share the difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry if I could express as I wish. As I tried to say @MichaelPetrotta I Need only the near divs around the click. but at the moment I'm getting all divs that are above my click (not only the first row) and all divs below (not only the first row)

Comment: @Radu Sorry, As I said, the left+right is from Minesweeper not from my example. In my example is only a normal click.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta , +Radu, I made some changes in the question to make things clear. I hope this will clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know what you rally want but try this:

```
$.expr[':'].xy = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
    var xy = meta[3].split(',');
    var x = xy[0];
    var y = xy[1];
    var el = $(obj);
    var el_offset = el.offset();
    return el_offset.left == y && (el_offset.top-el.height() == x || el_offset.top+el.height() == x);
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RCRQJ/4/)

**UPDATE:**

hmm you can select all of them like this:

```
$.expr[':'].xy = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
    var xy = meta[3].split(',');
    var y = xy[0];
    var x = xy[1];
    var el = $(obj);
    var el_offset = el.offset();
    // check for top and bottom 3 blocks
    if ((el_offset.top-el.height() == y || el_offset.top+el.height() == y) &&  (el_offset.left+el.width() == x || el_offset.left == x || el_offset.left-el.width() == x))
        return true;
    // left and right
    else if (el_offset.top == y && (el_offset.left+el.width() == x || el_offset.left-el.width() == x))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

and then do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function myfunction() {

    $('.content').on("click", function () {
        var obj_left = $(this).offset().left;
        var obj_top = $(this).offset().top;

        $('#wrap').find('.content:xy(' + obj_top + ',' + obj_left + ')').css('background-color', 'red');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked in your example, and it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Really thank you for the complement, I have removed that extra question of the comment because it was not part of the original question, and I was being a little abusive about it. But really thanks for the complement =)